# SignalR perde a conexão ao dar um PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

**A ideia é manter o usuário logado no *Chat* enquanto ele navega pelas paginas.**

---

Disposição dos componentes na página

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Layout.cshtml

  ```
  function iniciarChat() {

      var chatHub = $.connection.chat;
      $.connection.hub.start();

  }
  ```
- Index.cshtml

  ```
  iniciarChat();
  ```

Hoje a estrutura esta assim. Porem quando o usuário clica em algum link que efetue um PostBack, ele é desconectado do *Chat*. E quando ele volta para Index.cshtml, ele reconecta no *Chat* novamente.

**Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de manter o usuário conectado ao *Chat* mesmo que ele efetue um PostBack.**

Answer (score 1):

Qual a estrutura do seu `Hub`?

Acredito que você vai precisar fazer um controle no `OnDisconnected` e na hora de adicionar o usuário a uma nova sessão.

Quando ele "desconectar", você vai ter que manter ele ainda no mapeamento das sessões por X tempo esperando ele voltar, quando ele passar para a próxima página você apenas verifica se o usuário já tinha criado a sessão e atribui a ele novamente.

O problema maior vai ser nesse "gerenciamento" no tempo pra expirar, mas quanto a ele desconectar tudo depende do seu código no [`.OnDisconnected`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub.ondisconnected(v=vs.118).aspx).

Sobre "PostBack" ele só existe quando o usuário envia, por exemplo, um `submit` pro servidor e ele continua na página. Quando você navega entre páginas **não** é um *PostBack*. Então não é por esse caminho ;)

Comment: Ola @MaiconCarraro ! o problema é que quando o usuário muda de pagina, o código javascript das paginas Layout e Index são executados novamente e assim fazendo com que o hub reconecte.

Comment: @alexanderPataki Não tem como você não executar o javascript se não ele não vai receber as chamadas, o que tu faz é evitar de criar uma **NOVA** sessão

Comment: Como posso fazer isso? Pois quando o método iniciarChat() é executado, é como se fosse criado uma ponte entre o client e o Hub, e se sair da index.cshtml, ele logo cai no método OnDisconnected do Hub.